# Sql query optimisation for million records

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 entities `Customers` and `Agreements`.

Every customer could have 0..* agreements which could be `active=1` or `closed=0`.

I'm trying to select clients, who don't have any agreements (no records in table `Agreements`) or clients who have agreements with flag 'closed' = 0 in one query.

The agreements table has a few million records.

Any suggestions how to do it the best way?

Comment: You want clients have _any_ closed agreements or you want clients having _only_ closed agreements?  If a client had 3 closed agreements and 1 active agreement, would you want that client included in the query results?

Comment: exactly. I need clients who don't have aggrements (no records in table aggrements) and clients who have inactive aggrements (have a few records in tabele aggrements but minimum one is in status='closed')

Answer (score 1):

use correlated subquery, i gused you a relational column `customerid`

```
select c* from customer c
where  exists( select 1 from Aggrements a where c.customerid=a.customerid
                                          and a.closed=0)
or (not exists ( select 1 from Aggrements a where c.customerid=a.customerid
                                          and a.active=1)
   )
```

if you dont have index on customerid column do it 1st otherwise query will take time

Comment: Thx but i need one more think. In return query value in column exist: 1 := exist; 0 := not exist (in table aggrements)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `exists` and `not exists`, with this logic:

```
select c.*
from customers c
where not exists (select 1
                  from Agreements a
                  where a.customerid = c.customerid
                 ) or
     exists (select 1
             from Agreements a 
             where a.customerid = c.customerid and
                   a.closed = 0
            );
```

For performance, you want an index on `agreements(customerid, closed)`.